# No input file specified - Nginx - Magento

Tags: file, magento, input, nginx

i have a problem with my nginx server configuration.
I want to install a magento shop on a vhost.

Maybe someone can helps me.

Error:
No input file specified.

My configurations:
example.com

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    ## SSL directives might go here
    ## see http://www.howtoforge.com/how_to_set_up_ssl_vhosts_under_nginx_plus_sni_support_ubuntu_11.04_debian_squeeze
    ## if you want to enable SSL for this vhost

    server_name www.subdomain.example.com subdomain.example.com;
    root /var/www/www.subdomain.example.com/web;

    ## rewrites example.com to www.example.com
    if ($http_host != "www.subdomain.example.com") {
        rewrite ^ $scheme://www.subdomain.example.com$request_uri permanent;
    }

    location / {
        index index.html index.php; ## Allow a static html file to be shown first
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler; ## If missing pass the URI to Magento's front handler
        expires 30d; ## Assume all files are cachable
    }

    ## These locations would be hidden by .htaccess normally
    location /app/                { deny all; }
    location /includes/           { deny all; }
    location /lib/                { deny all; }
    location /media/downloadable/ { deny all; }
    location /pkginfo/            { deny all; }
    location /report/config.xml   { deny all; }
    location /var/                { deny all; }

    location /var/export/ { ## Allow admins only to view export folder
        auth_basic           "Restricted"; ## Message shown in login window
        auth_basic_user_file /var/www/www.subdomain.example.com/.htpasswd; ## See /etc/nginx/htpassword
        autoindex            on;
    }

    ## Disable .htaccess and other hidden files
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location @handler { ## Magento uses a common front handler
        rewrite / /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php/ { ## Forward paths like /js/index.php/x.js to relevant handler
        rewrite ^(.*\.php)/ $1 last;
    }

    location /phpmyadmin {
               root /usr/share/;
               index index.php index.html index.htm;
               location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
                       try_files $uri =404;
                       root /usr/share/;
                       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                       fastcgi_index index.php;
                       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                       include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
               }
               location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
                root /usr/share/;
               }
        }
        location /phpMyAdmin {
               rewrite ^/* /phpmyadmin last;
        }

    location ~ \.php$ { ## Execute PHP scripts
        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; } ## Catch 404s that try_files miss

        expires        off; ## Do not cache dynamic content
        #fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:8888;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param  HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE default; ## Store code is defined in administration > Configuration > Manage Stores
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
        include        fastcgi_params; ## See /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params
    }
}
```

nginx conf:

```
    user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

       map $scheme $fastcgi_https {
        default off;
        https on;
       }     

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

Would be very nice

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few things that could be wrong there, here's what I would try to start.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name subdomain.example.com;

    return 301 $scheme://www.subdomain.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    ## SSL directives might go here
    ## see http://www.howtoforge.com/how_to_set_up_ssl_vhosts_under_nginx_plus_sni_support_ubuntu_11.04_debian_squeeze
    ## if you want to enable SSL for this vhost

    server_name www.subdomain.example.com;
    root /var/www/www.subdomain.example.com/web;


    location / {
        index index.html index.php; ## Allow a static html file to be shown first
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        expires 30d; ## Assume all files are cachable
    }

    ## These locations would be hidden by .htaccess normally
    location /app/                { deny all; }
    location /includes/           { deny all; }
    location /lib/                { deny all; }
    location /media/downloadable/ { deny all; }
    location /pkginfo/            { deny all; }
    location /report/config.xml   { deny all; }
    location /var/                { deny all; }

    location /var/export/ { ## Allow admins only to view export folder
        auth_basic           "Restricted"; ## Message shown in login window
        auth_basic_user_file /var/www/www.subdomain.example.com/.htpasswd; ## See /etc/nginx/htpassword
        autoindex            on;
    }

    ## Disable .htaccess and other hidden files
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location ~ \.php/ { ## Forward paths like /js/index.php/x.js to relevant handler
        rewrite ^(.*\.php)/ $1 last;
    }

    location /phpmyadmin {
       root /usr/share/;
       index index.php index.html index.htm;

       location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
           try_files $uri =404;
           root /usr/share/;
           fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
           fastcgi_index index.php;
           fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
           include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
       }
       location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
            root /usr/share/;
       }
    }

    location /phpMyAdmin {
        rewrite ^/* /phpmyadmin last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ { ## Execute PHP scripts
        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; } ## Catch 404s that try_files miss

        expires        off; ## Do not cache dynamic content
        #fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:8888;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param  HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE default; ## Store code is defined in administration > Configuration > Manage Stores
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
        include        fastcgi_params; ## See /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params
    }
}
```

Here is also a working magento 1.9 config I use for reference:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name store.domain.com;

        #Add some security stuff to headers
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

        root /home/web/store;
        index index.php;

        # set expiration of assets to MAX for caching
        location ~* \.(ico|css|gif|jpe?g|png|js)(\?[0-9]+)?$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }

        location / {
                # Check if a file or directory index file exists, else route it to index.php.
                try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

        # deny access to .git files
        location ~ /\.git {
                deny all;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Brian. I put your config for testing it. But now i have the problem that it only show me the standard welcome page from nginx. Maybe you have a tip for me? There are nothing wrong after restarting nginx. vhosts created / symlink created

Comment: I have included /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/* in nginx.conf as you can see in the start post

Comment: Okay works till now. I have delete default completly. Thank you very very much (Y) Maybe do you have a tip for secure phpmyadmin access for this config?

Comment: On the frontend all works perfect. But if i want to login to the backend after i enter my login data, i only got a white page.

Comment: [error] 6412#0: *53 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function curl_setopt_array() in /var/www/MYPATH/lib/Varien/Http/Adapter/Curl.php on line 77" while reading response header from upstream,

Comment: Look like you need to add php-curl or php5-curl package to your installation.  As far as securing your phpmyadmin, you can add a location block for it and deny all then allow from just your IP address

Comment: Thank you. But Magento Connect Manager dont work with this config. I think there is something wrong with redirect. The URL looks like: downloader/?return=http%3A%2F%2FSITE.LTD%2Findex.php%2FADMINPATH%2F